# Rotate AVI video by 90 degree

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, libav

I used to apply this command to transcode videos of my mobile phone to AVI:

```
ffmpeg -i Input.mov -s 640x360 -sameq -vcodec msmpeg4v2 -acodec libmp3lame Output.avi
```

Now I'd like to rotate some videos by 90 degree, retaining the other quality options.

Using a rather old version of `ffmpeg`, it does not support the `-vfilters` option. So instead I used a more recent version of `avconv`, which does not support the `-sameq` option anymore ([which does not make a lot of sense anyway, as I learned](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Why-was-the-ffmpeg-_002dsameq-option-removed_003f-What-to-use-instead_003f)). However, the quality of my output became very bad. I fiddled around with the options (e.g. 640x360 -> 360x640), but nothing seemed to help. The video became very 'blocky'.

Basically, I want the exact same quality as with above command (or as close as possible), but rotate the output by 90 degree. I also tried to apply a rotate filter in `avidemux`, but it keeps crashing when I start the encoding process.

How can I properly call the new `avconv` version to obtain my goal? Is there any alternative tool you can recommend?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a newer version of ffmpeg?

Comment: The ``avconv`` program is part of ``libav``, which is Ubuntu's edition of ``ffmpeg``. So basically, I tried the most recent version of ``ffmpeg``.

Comment: No, you didn't. libav _isn't_ just "Ubuntu's edition of ffmpeg" – it is a _fork_, [developed independently](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/FFmpeg-versus-Libav) from the original ffmpeg. The ffmpeg developers merge many features from libav, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a recent build of ffmpeg* and run

```
ffmpeg -i Input.mov Output.mp4
```

- The video will be autorotated and encoded.
- If you want to re-mux ([stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy)) the audio instead of re-encoding it, then add `-c:a copy`, but it needs to be compatible with your output container format (ffmpeg will generally let you know if it is not).

<sub>*Get the latest nightly/snapshot static build for your OS [here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).</sub>

Comment: Got myself a static build of a recent ffmpeg version and I indeed managed to rotate the video. I had to add the ``-qscale 0`` option to preserve my initial video quality, however.